# load data into memory from ajax response in extjs

Tags: extjs

My json data look like this

```
//
//var data = {
//      
//
//      
//      
//     "success": true,
//     "users": [
//         {"id": 1, "name": 'Ed',    "email": "ed@sencha.com"},
//         {"id": 2, "name": 'Tommy', "email": "tommy@sencha.com"},
//         
//           {"id": 3, "name": 'Tommy', "email": "tommy@sencha.com"},
//           
//           {"id": 4, "name": 'Tommy', "email": "tommy@sencha.com"},
//           
//           {"id": 5, "name": 'Tommy', "email": "tommy@sencha.com"},
//       
//         {"id": 11, "name": 'Ed',    "email": "ed@sencha.com"},
//         {"id": 12, "name": 'Tommy', "email": "tommy@sencha.com"},
//         
//           {"id": 13, "name": 'Tommy', "email": "tommy@sencha.com"},
//           
//           {"id": 14, "name": 'Tommy', "email": "tommy@sencha.com"},
//           
//           {"id": 15, "name": 'Tommy', "email": "tommy@sencha.com"},
//           
//           
//             {"id": 21, "name": 'Ed',    "email": "ed@sencha.com"},
//         {"id": 22, "name": 'Tommy', "email": "tommy@sencha.com"},
//         
//           {"id": 23, "name": 'Tommy', "email": "tommy@sencha.com"},
//           
//           {"id": 24, "name": 'Tommy', "email": "tommy@sencha.com"},
//           
//           {"id": 25, "name": 'Tommy', "email": "tommy@sencha.com"},
//       
//         
//     ]
//  }       
//           







// this my store in extjs


var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'AM.model.User',
        pageSize : 10,

        autoLoad: true,
       data:data,

        proxy: {
            type: 'memory',

            enablePaging: true,
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'users',
                 totalProperty : 'total'
            }
        },








    });

// ajax request to call json data in json file

Ext.Ajax.request({
       url: 'app/data/users.json',

       success: function(response, opts) {
          var obj = response.responseText;


          store.loadData(resp.responseText, true); 

       },
       failure: function(response, opts) {
          console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
       }
    });



// this is my view .

Ext.define('AM.view.user.List' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.userlist',

    title: 'All Users',





    initComponent: function() {

        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
          title: 'Column Demo',
          store:store,
          columns: [
         {header: 'ID',  dataIndex:'id',flex:1},
              {header: 'Name',  dataIndex:'name',flex:1},
              {text: 'Email',  dataIndex:'email',flex:1},

          ],

         renderTo:'example-grid',
         width: 350,
         height: 285,
      dockedItems: [{
          xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
          store: store,   // same store GridPanel is using
          dock: 'bottom',
          pageSize: 10,
          prependButtons: true,
          displayInfo: true
      }],






          renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });


        store.loadPage(1);
      this.callParent(arguments);
  }



});
```

i am going to use paging .for that i need json data .that json data i get from ajax response.how to load ajax response json data into memory. can any one help me? .i am going in right way or wrong way  i dont no can any one help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to load ajax response in memory in extjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27762528/how-to-load-ajax-response-in-memory-in-extjs) -1

Comment: i am not getting answers for that

Comment: Well, that is not a reason for posting the same question twice. You should try to refactor your question instead

Comment: There **are** answers to your original question, especially the one that advices to not use Ext.Ajax.request but the built in store/proxy infrastructure. Have you done that?

Comment: i understand buddy.ajax call is for load data into store.but not in memory .if i use proxy in ajax then how can i use memory in proxy .can you give sample example or code helpfull to me @ saki

Answer (score 0):

resp.responseText returns a plain string.
Use JSON.parse(resp.responseText) instead.